# Creating Supply List in JQuery Mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

Alright so the task at hand is that I am creating basically a form for a school that has a multiple Custom select menu for Kindergarten through 8th grade.  I have the menus created.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
<title>Supply List</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"        charset="UTF-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div data-role="page">

    <div data-role="header">
        <h1> Supply List</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
        <form>
        <p>
            <div class="ui-field-contain">
        <lable for="select-custom-19">Kindergarten</lable>
        <select name="select-customer-19" id="select-custom-19" multiple="multiple" data-native-menu="false">
            <option>Kindergarten</option>
            <option value="1">(48) #2 6-sided pencils (sharpened preferred)</option>
            <option value="2">(2) Red Pencils</option>
            <option value="3">(2) 2-pocket plastic folders (1ea. 1 blue, 1 green)</option>
            <option value="4">(3) Box of 24ct crayons</option>
            <option value="5">(2) Dry erase markers (blue or black)</option>
            <option value="6">(1) Pencil box</option>
            <option value="7">(6) Glue sticks</option>
            <option value="8">(1) White 3-ring 1" binder</option>
            <option value="9">(1) Pack of pink erasers</option>
            <option value="10">(1) Pack of pencil cap erasers</option>
            <option value="11">(1) Box of Kleenex (tissue)</option>
        </select>
    </div>
        <div class="ui-field-contain">
            <lable for="select-custom-19">First Grade</lable>
            <select name="select-customer-19" id="select-custom-19" multiple="multiple" data-native-menu="false">
                <option>First Grade</option>
                <option value="1">(48) #2 6-sided pencils (sharpened preferred)</option>
                <option value="2">(2) Red Pencils</option>
                <option value="3">(2) 2-pocket plastic folders (1ea. 1 blue, 1 green)</option>
                <option value="4">(3) Box of 24ct crayons</option>
                <option value="5">(2) Dry erase markers (blue or black)</option>
                <option value="6">(1) Pencil box</option>
                <option value="7">(6) Glue sticks</option>
                <option value="8">(1) White 3-ring 1" binder</option>
                <option value="9">(1) Pack of pink erasers</option>
                <option value="10">(1) Pack of pencil cap erasers</option>
                <option value="11">(1) Box of Kleenex (tissue)</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="ui-field-contain">
            <lable for="select-custom-19">Second Grade</lable>
            <select name="select-customer-19" id="select-custom-19" multiple="multiple" data-native-menu="false">
                <option>Second Grade</option>
                <option value="1">(48) #2 6-sided pencils (sharpened preferred)</option>
                <option value="2">(2) Red Pencils</option>
                <option value="3">(2) 2-pocket plastic folders (1ea. 1 blue, 1 green)</option>
                <option value="4">(3) Box of 24ct crayons</option>
                <option value="5">(2) Dry erase markers (blue or black)</option>
                <option value="6">(1) Pencil box</option>
                <option value="7">(6) Glue sticks</option>
                <option value="8">(1) White 3-ring 1" binder</option>
                <option value="9">(1) Pack of pink erasers</option>
                <option value="10">(1) Pack of pencil cap erasers</option>
                <option value="11">(1) Box of Kleenex (tissue)</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="ui-field-contain">
            <lable for="select-custom-19">Third Grade</lable>
            <select name="select-customer-19" id="select-custom-19" multiple="multiple" data-native-menu="false">
                <option>Third Grade</option>
                <option value="1">(48) #2 6-sided pencils (sharpened preferred)</option>
                <option value="2">(2) Red Pencils</option>
                <option value="3">(2) 2-pocket plastic folders (1ea. 1 blue, 1 green)</option>
                <option value="4">(3) Box of 24ct crayons</option>
                <option value="5">(2) Dry erase markers (blue or black)</option>
                <option value="6">(1) Pencil box</option>
                <option value="7">(6) Glue sticks</option>
                <option value="8">(1) White 3-ring 1" binder</option>
                <option value="9">(1) Pack of pink erasers</option>
                <option value="10">(1) Pack of pencil cap erasers</option>
                <option value="11">(1) Box of Kleenex (tissue)</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="ui-field-contain">
            <lable for="select-custom-19">Fourth Grade</lable>
            <select name="select-customer-19" id="select-custom-19" multiple="multiple" data-native-menu="false">
                <option>Fourth Grade</option>
                <option value="1">(48) #2 6-sided pencils (sharpened preferred)</option>
                <option value="2">(2) Red Pencils</option>
                <option value="3">(2) 2-pocket plastic folders (1ea. 1 blue, 1 green)</option>
                <option value="4">(3) Box of 24ct crayons</option>
                <option value="5">(2) Dry erase markers (blue or black)</option>
                <option value="6">(1) Pencil box</option>
                <option value="7">(6) Glue sticks</option>
                <option value="8">(1) White 3-ring 1" binder</option>
                <option value="9">(1) Pack of pink erasers</option>
                <option value="10">(1) Pack of pencil cap erasers</option>
                <option value="11">(1) Box of Kleenex (tissue)</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="ui-field-contain">
            <lable for="select-custom-19">Fifth Grade</lable>
            <select name="select-customer-19" id="select-custom-19" multiple="multiple" data-native-menu="false">
                <option>Fifth Grade</option>
                <option value="1">(48) #2 6-sided pencils (sharpened preferred)</option>
                <option value="2">(2) Red Pencils</option>
                <option value="3">(2) 2-pocket plastic folders (1ea. 1 blue, 1 green)</option>
                <option value="4">(3) Box of 24ct crayons</option>
                <option value="5">(2) Dry erase markers (blue or black)</option>
                <option value="6">(1) Pencil box</option>
                <option value="7">(6) Glue sticks</option>
                <option value="8">(1) White 3-ring 1" binder</option>
                <option value="9">(1) Pack of pink erasers</option>
                <option value="10">(1) Pack of pencil cap erasers</option>
                <option value="11">(1) Box of Kleenex (tissue)</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="ui-field-contain">
            <lable for="select-custom-19">Sixth Grade</lable>
            <select name="select-customer-19" id="select-custom-19" multiple="multiple" data-native-menu="false">
                <option>Sixth Grade</option>
                <option value="1">(48) #2 6-sided pencils (sharpened preferred)</option>
                <option value="2">(2) Red Pencils</option>
                <option value="3">(2) 2-pocket plastic folders (1ea. 1 blue, 1 green)</option>
                <option value="4">(3) Box of 24ct crayons</option>
                <option value="5">(2) Dry erase markers (blue or black)</option>
                <option value="6">(1) Pencil box</option>
                <option value="7">(6) Glue sticks</option>
                <option value="8">(1) White 3-ring 1" binder</option>
                <option value="9">(1) Pack of pink erasers</option>
                <option value="10">(1) Pack of pencil cap erasers</option>
                <option value="11">(1) Box of Kleenex (tissue)</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="ui-field-contain">
            <lable for="select-custom-19">Seventh Grade</lable>
            <select name="select-customer-19" id="select-custom-19" multiple="multiple" data-native-menu="false">
                <option>Seventh Grade</option>
                <option value="1">(48) #2 6-sided pencils (sharpened preferred)</option>
                <option value="2">(2) Red Pencils</option>
                <option value="3">(2) 2-pocket plastic folders (1ea. 1 blue, 1 green)</option>
                <option value="4">(3) Box of 24ct crayons</option>
                <option value="5">(2) Dry erase markers (blue or black)</option>
                <option value="6">(1) Pencil box</option>
                <option value="7">(6) Glue sticks</option>
                <option value="8">(1) White 3-ring 1" binder</option>
                <option value="9">(1) Pack of pink erasers</option>
                <option value="10">(1) Pack of pencil cap erasers</option>
                <option value="11">(1) Box of Kleenex (tissue)</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="ui-field-contain">
            <lable for="select-custom-19">Eighth Grade</lable>
            <select name="select-customer-19" id="select-custom-19" multiple="multiple" data-native-menu="false">
                <option>Eighth Grade</option>
                <option value="1">(48) #2 6-sided pencils (sharpened preferred)</option>
                <option value="2">(2) Red Pencils</option>
                <option value="3">(2) 2-pocket plastic folders (1ea. 1 blue, 1 green)</option>
                <option value="4">(3) Box of 24ct crayons</option>
                <option value="5">(2) Dry erase markers (blue or black)</option>
                <option value="6">(1) Pencil box</option>
                <option value="7">(6) Glue sticks</option>
                <option value="8">(1) White 3-ring 1" binder</option>
                <option value="9">(1) Pack of pink erasers</option>
                <option value="10">(1) Pack of pencil cap erasers</option>
                <option value="11">(1) Box of Kleenex (tissue)</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        </p>
            </form>
        <button class="ui-btn ui-corner-all SupplyList">Supply List</button>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

So the step that I am stuck on is how to open a new page with a list of all the items that were selected off of the multiple Custom select menus.  So that when they click the button called Supply List it will combine all that was selected and they will have a easy to look at Supply list to go shopping for.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a second page to your markup, e.g.:

```
<div data-role="page" id="page2">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1> Chosen</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">        
        <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" id="lstChosen"></ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have put an empty listview in the page, which will be populated when you click the button in the first page. On the first page I have changes the button to a link with an ID:

```
<a href="#page2" id="btnSupply" class="SupplyList" data-role="button">Supply List</a>
```

When you click this button, it will navigate to page 2 and the script will populate the list:

```
$(document).on("pageinit", "#page1", function(){
    $("#btnSupply").on("click", function(){
        var html = '';
        $("#frmSupply select").each(function(idx){
            var grade = $(this).find("option:first-child").text();
            var sel = $(this).find("option:selected");
            if (sel.length > 0){
                html += '<li data-role="list-divider" >' + grade + '</li>'; 
                sel.each(function(idx){
                    html += '<li>' + $(this).text() + '</li>';
                });
            }

        });
        $("#lstChosen").empty().append(html).listview("refresh");
    });
});
```

This script iterates through all SELECT elements within the form.  For each one it gets the grade name from the first option and then a list of the selected options if any. If selected options are found, create a list divider with the grade name and list items for each selected option. Finally append all the created listitems to the listview in page 2.

> Here is a **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/7k9h9ez7/1/)**